# Notepad++ file has been changed, would you like to reload?

Tags: notepad++, data-recovery

I pressed YES, but I have made a huge mistake. Can I get the state before I press "reload"?

Comment: I'm afraid you can't do anything ;(

Comment: In most cases, no. If you work on a terminal server and VSS is turned on, then you may be able to find a previous snapshot, but only from the file itself before editing. AKA backups.